# My Led blinks rapidly at the reset and stop blinking instantly

Tags: arduino-uno

So ive been trying to make a program to test if the pins are working correctly but all it does is make my led blink rapidly on reset. the point of the program is that all my pins are connected to the same led, so blink each one of them once and send the number of the blinked pin to the serial.
but the led just doesnt blink and the program gets stuck at the start of pwmoutputtest.

````
boolean byteinarray(byte array[], byte pbit){
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    if(array[i]==pbit){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void outputtest(){
  for(byte i=2;i<13;i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }

  for(byte i=2;i<14;i++){
    if (byteinarray(pwm, i)==false){
      Serial.println(i);
      digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(i, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}

void analogoutputtest(){
  for(byte i=0;i<5;i++) {
    pinMode("A"+i, OUTPUT);
  }

  for(int i=A0;i<A5;i++){
    Serial.println(i);
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  } 
}


void pwmoutputtest (){
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    pinMode(pwm[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    Serial.println(pwm[i]);
    for(int j=0; i<200; i++){
      analogWrite(pwm[i], j);
      delay(5);
    }
    analogWrite(pwm[i], 0);
  }
}



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  outputtest();
  pwmoutputtest();
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have connected all the pins together. Then you are setting one pin HIGH (5V) at a time while all others are LOW (0V, aka ground).

So basically you are creating a short each time you set a pin HIGH. The current won't flow through the LED to ground (which would light up the LED), but the current flows through the pins, that are LOW, to ground. And since you didn't mention any current limiting resistors, you are straining the pin output hardware with this massively. If you do this too much, the pin output hardware will fail at some point, making the pin unusable for digital IO.

Instead of keeping the other pins LOW, you need to keep them at high impedance , which means configuring them as INPUT. That would be a function like this (not tested):

```
void outputtest(){
  for(byte i=2;i<13;i++) {
    pinMode(i, INPUT);
  }

  for(byte i=2;i<14;i++){
    if (byteinarray(pwm, i)==false){
      Serial.println(i);
      pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(i, LOW);
      pinMode(i, INPUT);
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tysm i hope i didnt break anything

Comment: @Lucas If you think this answered your question, then you can accept my answer to mark your question as solved